# Item separator line are not shown all in ListView! maybe textSize is the reason or Bug?

Tags: android

As you can see in this screenshoot ListView doesn't show all item separator, seems that the problem is setting textSize for textView, if i remove textSize all work fine.

Thanks in advance for any replay!

This is a little testcase:

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

```
ListView lv=getListView();
lv.setDividerHeight(2);
```